# Custom view doesn't appear?

Tags: android, layout, view

I've defined a view that extends LinearLayout, which I want to put in a ViewAnimator. Trouble is, it doesn't show up.
I'm not using XML for the layouts, so I have a class that extends LinearLayout, for example:

```
public class DetailView extends LinearLayout {

ImageView mImageView;
TextView mTxtName;

public DetailView(Context context) {
    super(context);     
    mTxtName = new TextView(context);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpn.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
    mTxtName.setLayoutParams(lpn);
    mTxtName.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);


    mImageView = new ImageView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpi = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpi.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
    mImageView.setLayoutParams(lpi);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wait);
}
```

Then in my activity I add it thus:

```
va = new ViewAnimator(this);
detail = new DetailView(this);
        detail.setOrientation(1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams dLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
va.setLayoutParams(dLayout);
va.addView(detail,0);
```

But it doesn't show. I'm missing something stupidly obvious, I'm sure.

Comment: Does `va` ever get added to your layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you never call `addView` to add the child `Views` into your `ViewGroup`.  It would be something like:

```
    public DetailView(Context context) {
        super(context);     
        mTxtName = new TextView(context);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpn.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
        mTxtName.setLayoutParams(lpn);
        mTxtName.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
        this.addView(mTxtName);//add the view to your viewgroup

        mImageView = new ImageView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpi = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpi.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
    mImageView.setLayoutParams(lpi);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wait);
    this.addView(mImageView);
}
```

Comment: That was exactly it- I knew it would be something simple! Thanks